# Residency under EU law for a spouse of an Austrian who is not an EU citizen

Tags: citizenship, eu, austria

My wife and I are citizens of a non EU country and we don't speak German. I have got my Austrian citizenship recently and we want to live and work in Austria. From what I read I know, that in order to obtain residence title of “Family Member” she has to provide evidence of German language skills on A1 level. Is it possible for us to live and work in Austria under EU law? Otherwise, is it possible that I can live in one of the EU countries under EU law and then we move to Austria and live under EU law without the language requirement?

Answer (score 1):

EU law doesn't readily apply to you if you only ever lived in Austria but it is indeed possible to benefit from it when coming back to Austria after living *together* (not you alone) elsewhere in the EU. This is called the ”Surinder Singh route”. A lot of the literature online refers to the UK as that's where the original case stemmed from. It doesn't apply there anymore since Brexit but the precedent still applies in the EU.